# How to get all languages translations - Joomla3 / Php

Tags: php, translation, joomla3.0, multilingual, lang

I make a custom sitemap generator engine in Joomla 3.6. And I want all translations in this sitemap. I've got 8 differents active lang.

When I generate my sitemap from `www.mysite.com/en`, with `JText::_('A_KEY');`, I get only the english translation. But I need all of others.

Is it possible to specify the language to JText? A bit like `JText::_('A_KEY',$lang_code);`. Or instance a custom JText for each other languages ?
Thank you!

Comment: `en` makes seem quite reasonable that you would only get English results.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).